# how to call an array after loading in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a problem in calling an array after loading in a for loop in python.

Actually, my written code is as below:

```
d1 = 'c:\ex\A'
d2 = '.txt'
for i in range(10):
    d3 = str(i)
    dire = d1 + d3 + d2
    a(i) = np.loadtxt(dire)
```

After pressing enter this error appears:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

My question is this: how can I call `a(1)` to `a(9)`?

Comment: array elements are addressed with square brackets: `a[i]`.

Comment: Is `a()` a function that gets one parameter which is a number in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing is performed with a square bracket `[]` notation when using arrays (either `list()` or `array` from the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) package). It is most commonly used after an array has been populated.

To populate an array, that is add to an array, you commonly use the [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method and don't use assignment.

Your code should be changed to add the append method in order to save each files contents, I'll assume `a` is a list:

```
d1 = 'c:\ex\A'
d2 = '.txt'
a = []  # create empty list
for i in range(10):
    d3 = str(i)
    dire = d1 + d3 + d2

    # add to list
    # no need for indexing
    a.append(np.loadtxt(dire))
```

Comment: Thank you. specially Dimitris Jim. Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `a[i]` instead of `a(i)`

```
d1 = 'c:\ex\A'
d2 = '.txt'
for i in range(10):
    d3 = str(i)
    dire = d1 + d3 + d2
    a[i] = np.loadtxt(dire)
```